# FitNesse Test History with Version Control

Tags: version-control, automated-tests, fitnesse

I'm starting some automated acceptance testing for our company, and have decided to use FitNesse.

I want to have FitNesse under source control - that is the FitNesse executable + plugins, the wiki pages and the test fixture source code.

Then anyone can get all they need from source control to build and run the acceptance tests  locally. Including a Continuous Integration server.

I have read that the page versioning can be turned off using the -e 0 parameters. Then we don't have ZIP files in the FitNesse root folder under source control - nice.

But what about **Test History**? Do I want the history of locally ran tests to be checked in? And when someone gets the latest version, do they want their local test history to be overwritten?

I'm very grateful to anyone who can share their experiences of using FitNesse in similar scenarios to that described above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you not clear all test history before check-in?

In my current project, there are only 2 required operations for creating test cases on FitNesse: Drawing the table(Edit the page) and developing the api(output as .dll files).

We also develop a tool for triggering the FitNesse running testing from remote machines automatically. After finish testing, we get the testing result by handling the output excel files.

The structure of our svn:

```
-SVN
 --FitNess
  --- TestLib
  --- FitNesse
     ---- FitNesseBin
     ---- TestCases
```

[Update]

Test Fixture code should be finished and frozen before testers start writing test cases and running them. Certainly, when Test Fixture need bug fixing or enhancement, the code could also be changed. In my team, we ask different roles to handle different tasks. Developer provide API for testing use. Senior QA wrap the API in test fixture. QA write the table/wiki. Every role only take the assigned parts. Before modification, team member should update local copy of the FixNesse, and check-out the file. And only check-in the modified check-outed file.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Do you keep your FitNesse Wiki under source control, so all developers have their own local version? Or do you have a 'centralised' installation with backup?

Comment: Yes, we upload the whole FitNesse folder which contains wiki page to SVN. We do not run FitNesse locally besides debugging the test cases.

Comment: BTW, we do not upload the local running history to svn since we would deploy FitNesse to remote test machines for testing once the new builds were released. After running, we will get the testing result from the .csv file which could be located at FitNesse folder. So the local history is useless for us. Even more, local history would mislead us.

Comment: Really appreciate your help. I have a couple of more questions, just to be clear I understand how you use fitNesse: How you go about writing a new test, or in general how you edit the Wiki? Do you do it locally and then check in, together with any necessary changes to the testFixture code? Do non-developers do this or only developers? In my experience only developers are comfortable using source control.

Comment: If your boss is miser, you would be broaden yours outlook by using SVN and MS Excel to manage manual test cases and test results. ;) So, testers/qa would also use SVN for some special scenarios.

Comment: And since the comment has limit characters and poor format, i add my option to my answer directly.

Comment: Thanks for your help - I got a good idea now of how to implement this to suit our team.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling and auto-purging of test history is still a valid requirement for those integrating fitnesse into a standard build (e.g. Maven) and for running fitnesse builds locally, despite .svnignore .gitignore etc options.

The test history slows down the finalisation of the test and when it's purged after a few runs you will certainly notice the difference.

Uncle Bob mentioned he was working on an option to only keep the test history for the latest test run (you always need at least 1 so you can show the results) here http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/fitnesse/message/14306 but cannot see such an option in the code. I got a python error trying to reply to post - so no answer on that option unfortunately :-(